# Instructor provided an assignment rubric that has no point distribution

Tags: undergraduate, grading, instructor

I'm wondering if someone could offer some professional advice regarding how I should approach a situation at my university. Essentially, we had a paper due for an English class, and the instructor provided a rubric. This rubric consists of six categories that are each worth 0 points, followed by a holistic assessment category worth 100 points that is a sum total of the other six categories.

I emailed the professor voicing my concern that without a point distribution in place (0 points for each category), there is no way for us to determine whether the grading was performed objectively, or even how to interpret a grade in a certain category. I asked him for clarification, and he said that the maximum number of points any category can have is 16.67. This, of course, implies that the categories are equally weighed. So I told him that this is also concerning for two reasons:

1) Not all categories should be weighed equally (content is not nearly as important as mechanics, for example)

2) It doesn't make sense to have a category worth "16.67" points max, since that implies you could earn a 14.17/16.67, and who is to say that 14.17 shouldn't have been a 14.18?

He responded saying they aren't weighed equally, which seems to contradict what he said before. Because if they are not weighed equally, then the maximum score any particular category can have (in the extreme case) is 95, with the remaining 5 points distributed among the other five categories.

So I'm not really getting anywhere with the professor; it doesn't seem like he understands the implications of not disclosing the point distribution on the rubric. How should I approach this situation?

Comment: Why do you want to know this? Maybe that can give you a more productive avenue of communication with your prof.

Comment: @MaartenBuis Well, I think it's fairly self-explanatory. Suppose I get a 90/100 on the assignment. How do I interpret that in terms of the categories I was graded on? Let's say the teacher claims I got 10 points in the content category. Is that good or bad? Without that transparency, I won't know if I was graded fairly or if the teacher was simply throwing around numbers that "felt" right.

Comment: You appear to believe that an essay can be uniquely and mechanically graded. This is not the case, since, for example, style or grammar problems can make specific points difficult to follow. While more guidance about what might be emphasized in the assessment (logic over grammar for instance) could be useful, in the end one assesses the essay as a whole.

Comment: @AleksandrH no that is not self-explanatory, and is still not clear. Do you want to learn how you can improve yourself, or do you want to check if the instructor was fair?

Comment: @MaartenBuis I can't do the first if the instructor graded unfairly, now, can I? Because then I don't know if I really did poorly or if they just came up with a random number and plugged it into the holistic assessment category.

Comment: @JonCuster Don't exaggerate. Of course it can't. Essays are, to some degree, subjectively graded. But there's a reason those six categories are there—we are being graded on how well we did in those areas. If the distributions are not provided, we can't be certain that the grading was done properly. There's no transparency. The teacher could claim a category was worth 10 points max. And how would I dispute that if the information was not provided beforehand? I don't see why this is difficult to grasp, tbh. "Hey, let's make an already subjective assessment even more subjective." Perfect logic.

Comment: You are an undergraduate. Soon, you will have graduated and your assignments in the workplace will not have a rubric, and won't be graded on a curve.  How will you possible do a good job? You know what is considered important on the assignment from the rubric. Go write a good essay taking all that into account.

Comment: @AleksandrH yes you can, and you should. The grade is just a number. If you want to learn from your mistakes, then it is highly inefficient to start from there. You should identify your mistakes and learn form them, whether those mistakes cost you 1 point or 2 is immaterial. I suspect your communication with your instructor got derailed because you weren't focusing on the right thing.

Comment: @JonCuster To be fair, comparing performance on an essay to performance on the job is a bit of a stretch, but I get your point. For the time being, since this is an academic environment and teachers are expected to grade fairly, and since a rubric was provided, it's only logical for the instructor to also be transparent about the category weights. Simple as that.

Comment: What grading results is this professor providing? If all you get is one "holistic" number, then I'd agree with you that this is not enough information to help you improve. It would be better to get 6 numbers, one for each category. Better yet would be to get comments about what exactly should be improved --- red ink all over your essay. (Caution: When I was an undergraduate, my worst grades were in English classes, so don't give too much weight to my comment here.)

Comment: Have you received your grade back yet?  If not, you may want to defer the whole matter until then.  The grading scheme may make more sense once you have seen how it is carried out in practice.  And if you are happy with your grade, the whole question will be moot anyway.

Comment: Although I am in favor of rubrics with points attached, instructors are under no obligation to provide them. (Most of us of a certain age went through a complete academic career without ever seeing or hearing about a "rubric" at all.) As one systemic example, the Blackboard learning management system has on on/off switch for whether rubrics with point values have those point values displayed to students or not. Clearly both settings get used.

Answer (score 15):

I think you have a misperception regarding the extent to which your professors owe you a scientifically accurate accounting of their grading methodology. That extent is, to put it mildly, rather minimal. So, while your professor certainly has a duty to grade your work fairly, he has no obligation to provide you with extensive evidence that he has done so. I suspect that your efforts to reason with him that he should be more transparent about his grading methodology are doomed to failure and would only serve to annoy him.

Moreover, your sarcastic quip ‘“Hey, let’s make an already subjective assessment even more subjective.” Perfect logic.’ suggests a related misguided premise that fairness is inversely proportional to subjectivity. I don’t think that’s true. I am a math professor, and even in math where you would think there is an objective truth regarding what constitutes a right versus a wrong solution to a problem, grading often boils down to highly subjective value judgments that professors and students (as well as professors and TAs, and even professors and other professors) frequently disagree over. A rubric may create the illusion of objectivity, but will ultimately fail to measure the things that most professors think are the right things to measure when assessing students’ work. I’m guessing that your professor’s resistance to your request that he articulate his grading scheme in precisely quantifiable, algorithmic terms has more to do with his wish to grade you *more fairly*, according to his own definition of fairness, than with some nefarious intent on his part to grade your essay in bad faith.

TL;DR: listen to the advice of experienced people here who think your professor’s behavior is reasonable, accept the fact that you cannot monitor the honesty of every person who has decision-making powers over you, and find more worthwhile things to worry about — like writing such an amazing essay that the professor will have no choice but to give you a perfect score.

Answer (score 4):

Essay grading in English at the college and graduate level is usually not completely granular. That is to say, if you, for example, misspell a word or miss a comma, you will likely not see a straight docking to your grade. Consistently poor writing, though, will lead to grade reduction. I have not always been a fan of writing, but I did due diligence through undergrad taking Humanities courses and writing papers, and have never received a point-breakdown rubric aside from a loose description of what is expected.

It's been a decade since I've taken a pure English class, but much more recently that I've taken the GRE and GMAT. While not shining examples of essay prompts by any means, give you a numerical grade for your written efforts with only loose descriptions of the categorical requirements.

[When you compare a 6 (the top score) and a 5 (the second-highest score):](https://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/prepare/analytical_writing/argument/scoring_guide)

> In addressing the specific task directions, a 6 response presents a cogent, well-articulated examination of the argument and conveys meaning skillfully.

versus

> In addressing the specific task directions, a 5 response presents a generally thoughtful, well-developed examination of the argument and conveys meaning clearly.

There's not much that separates a 6 from a 5, but if you [read the sample answers](https://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/prepare/analytical_writing/argument/sample_responses) you should be able to tell there are subtle differences that make the 6 paper superior to the 5.

At this level of writing, I don't believe you still need a point-by-point breakdown to write a paper. You know, from the rubric, exactly what ingredients you need to put together to get that A. You just have to write it all.

The five-paragraph essay format, taught in high school, is great for handling all those English tests, but largely fails to capture the strength of free-form writing that becomes more prevalent in college. Does this mean a lot of subjectivity inherently comes into play for your grades? Of course. But if you write well and follow the basic guidelines, you will predominantly get As on your writing assignments.

I believe what the professor is trying to get at is that he is grading your writing as a completed product, especially considering each category is likely intertwined. I, for one, cannot imagine a paper getting any more than an F if it is a five-page paragraph with run-on sentences and spelling errors, or an eloquent paper documenting the rise and fall of Rome when the essay topic is supposed to be about writer's block.

Comment: I agree, I don't need a point-by-point breakdown to *write* the paper (I already wrote it and, in my opinion, far surpassed the requirements). What I *do* need the point distribution for is to assess whether the instructor/TA graded my paper fairly.

Comment: @AleksandrH Actually, you *want* the point distribution. As a great sage once said, "You can't always get what you want". Besides, as others have explained, what you want does not exist.